# How can I determine if a package was built from source?

Tags: centos6

I am trying to determine if httpd is from the rpm or a custom build.

`httpd -v` returns

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  3 2015 12:06:14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rpm -qa`and/or `yum list installed` to get a list of the installed packages.

```
rpm -qa httpd
```

or

```
yum list installed httpd
```

If the relevant httpd package isn't installed then you httpd was definitely compiled.

The above would determine if a relevant package had been installed but wouldn't help if a binary had later been compiled and then used to overwrite the original.

You can verify the files from an rpm

```
rpm -V httpd
```

this would tell you if files in the httpd package had changed since being installed.